# Fastest way to generate the absolute paths of all the files in a folder recursively in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, list, glob

My requirement is to generate a list of the absolute path of all the files in a Windows folder recursively.

I have tried glob.glob and glob.iglob but both take around 1.5 hours to generate the list.

Now it wouldn’t be a problem if it was a one-off situation. This program would run daily - and this is where the problem starts.

After the first time run, I would only need to get the list of the latest modified files (after the last run, using the timestamp of that run). This is so that even if the first run takes 1.5 hours, the daily run should take a few minutes at max. Now there is no way I can get the timestamp of each individual file without going through each of the files which means I would need to go through the entire folder regardless and check for the timestamp on each of those.

Can I optimize this in any way? Sure ideally, the data would be arranged by date but it’s not the case.

Comment: How many files are there?  How are you generating the list (show code)?  Do you actually need a list, or can you use a generator which will yield one path at a time?  I notice you say "windows" - it wouldn't surprise me if there were some performance penalties associated with obtaining timestamps associated with pythons posix-like model for file-handling.  Basically, you don't want "fastest way to generate the absolute paths of all the files in a folder", you want "much faster way to generate the absolute paths of files which have changed since a point in time".

Comment: I tried doing the same thing with PowerShell. There is a little bit of speed-up, but it’s not significant enough to make a huge difference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there are pure Python approaches that will be faster. You basically want to have a service running that keeps track of changes in real-time.
In principle you could put the whole folder under version control (Git), and check the pending changes once per day.

Comment: Ideally, putting the data in VCS seems like a good idea but the amount of authority required to transfer this data to Git would be abysmal. If that can be done, it would be better to just request the daily data to be added in a particular format under each specific date from hereon.

Comment: Keep in mind that Git does not necessarily mean GitHub. Git can be used fully offline, and it would simply create a .git repository inside the folder.

Comment: I do understand. I use GitLab anyway. But the issue is that we won’t have the permission to even install Git in the on-premises server in production.